# How did this question get an answer after it was closed?

Tags: support, bug, closed-questions

According to [the timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/82203/timeline), the question [Why haven't the Sith tried to harvest midichlorian?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82203/5184) was closed as a duplicate at 19:51 UTC.

It then received [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82206/5184) at 20:00 UTC.

Questions aren't supposed to be able to have answers posted after closing. I've been blocked from posting when I've been in the middle of writing an answer and the question has been closed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/172958